Subclass with generic type parameter declared as non-nullable accepts passing null value
I am learning generics and I have written such a class, but I am not quite sure how it works.
This is the code:
sealed class Result<out T> {
    abstract val data: T?
    abstract val error: String?

    class Success<out T>(override val data: T) : Result<T>() {
        override val error: String? = null
    }

    class Error<out T>(override val error: String, override val data: T? = null) : Result<T>()
}

fun main() {
    val resultNullable = getResultNullable()
    println(resultNullable.data)
}

fun getResultNullable(): Result<String?> {
    return Result.Success(null)
}

This code works fine, but I wonder why this line doesn't throw any error:
return Result.Success(null)

The class Success is declared to accept non-nullable value of type T, but it indeed accepts null.
Shouldn't it be declared as below to accept null values?
class Success<out T>(override val data: T?) : Result<T>() {
        override val error: String? = null
    }

I was searching for an explanation on the web, but I am struggling with understanding, so I decided to bring my own example here.
Thank you in advance for any support.

T is a generic type parameter, it doesn't say anything about the nullability of the type it can represent, because it's not constrained in any way. Users of the Result class can use either a nullable type OR a non-nullable type for T.
The return type of getResultNullable() is Result<String?> (note the question mark), so for this particular result, T = String?. This is why it's completely fine to create an instance with Result.Success(null).
You can see type parameters a bit like function parameters, but for types. While a function parameter s: String can be set to any value of type String, a type parameter T can be "set" to any type, nullable or not.
That being said, just like you can constrain the type of a function parameter, you can also add constraints on a type parameter. For instance, using T : Any ensure only non-nullable types are passed as T, because the type T has to be a subtype of Any (which is not nullable). The absence of constraints is equivalent to T : Any?.
About using T
So far we've only talked about the declaration of T in the class, such as class Success<out T>, but not the usages of it throughout the generic class or function.
When using T as the return type of a function, or as a function parameter type, we can add further variations of it:

no matter what the actual T is, we can refer to the nullable version of it by using T?. If T is String, then T? is String?. If T is already String?, then T? is also String?.

the opposite concept is the non-nullable version of T, and its denoted as T & Any. If T is String, then T & Any is String as well (already non-nullable). If T is String?, then T & Any is the non-nullable String.


These things can be useful in cases where we deal with null explicitly and generically. For instance:
// no matter what T is, this could return null
fun <T> makeNullMaybe(value: T): T? {
    if (Random.nextBoolean()) {
        return null
    } else {
        return value
    }
}

// no matter what T is, this will return a non-null value
fun <T> nonNullOrThrow(value: T): T & Any {
    if (value == null) {
        error("it's null!")
    }
    return value // smart-cast to the non-nullable version of T
}


I'm not sure why he thought that T is a non-nullable type. Maybe because he marked data as having type T?. I thinks it's worth mentioning that no matter what type T is, you can declare properties as the nullable version of that type.

Good point. I added a section about this.

@Joffrey The main goal of this class is to make possible returning results from repository methods with explicitly marked data's nullability. For example compiler should be aware that method that returns Result<String> always has non-nullable data field value to avoid null checks and the method that returns Result<String?> has nullable data value.
This is the case for Success instance. For Error instance, method that returns Result<String> should be able to return Error with null data (data here is optional).
Is there any room for improvements in this class?

@Josh I thought that T is a non-nullable type, becaues it misses question mark. I thought that T is always non-nullable by definition and T? is nullable - same as with String and String?. According to your responses i see that i was wrong. Thanks ;)

@K0cur regarding your first message, the expectations you described should be met by the implementation in the first snippet of your question. getResultNullable returns Result<String?>, so it's normal that it accepts null

@K0cur I thought that T is a non-nullable type, becaues it misses question mark - I understand the confusion. A way to think about this is rather to consider T (without question mark) like a variable/parameter name, and its value is a type (nullable or not, decided by the consumer/caller).
